# Exec Command doesnt seem to be executing properly in java

Tags: java, exec, runtime.exec

I have a java project built that I want to run from another java program. But when I call it using the exec command it does not execute immediately but waits for the current program to end. If I add a waitFor statement then the Program hangs as the main program waits for the process and the Process is waiting for the Main program. Does anyone know how I can solve this? Or why it is behaving in such a manner? I need this jar file to execute before a second one can.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -jar \"JavaProject1/dist/JavaProject1.jar\"");
        System.out.println("Hello");
        p.waitFor();
```

The location of the jar file is fine and it prints the hello. The main class for the jar file I want to run is in this thread at [DaniWeb](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/java/threads/350024/1486091#post1486091)

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Start the Java application and continue with the current processing?

Answer (score 1):

Amongst other things, you have to keep reading from the processes STDOUT and STDERR, otherwise it will block.

See, for example, http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html

Answer (score 0):

> why it is behaving in such a manner?

Because You are creating deadlock in your own program.

When you add `waitFor()` your program **main()** in this case waits for the external process to get finished.

It returns Zero when the external process gets fnished normally.

May be the external program has some issues

Comment: The external program runs well on its own. Yes I know the purpose of waitfor what I dont get is why is the External process not executing?